# How can I programmatically interact between iOS and OS X apps?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

This may sound a little strange, so I have to tell you *why* I am making this app. I just got a very old iMac that has very low processing power. I am attempting to make an application for my iPod Touch that can make it act as an external processor for OS X Panther. I have almost everything worked out, but I need the iPhone to be able to interact directly with the OS X app I am making, like iTunes does.

To be clear, I only want the iPod to work as an external processor by moving data from my OS X app to the iPod app, complete the code blocks, and send it back (thats the easy part). It does not have to work with any other OS X app. What I need to know is how I can send data through the cable to my iOS app directly. If this cannot be done, I have a backup data transmitting solution, but the cable would be much faster. Any ideas?

Comment: Just use WiFi. Yes, there are ways to move files back and forth over USB, but no way to "interact" like you could over a network connection.

Answer (score 2):

Good idea, don't post good idea's online ;-)

I'm going to tell you up front; unless you are lucky I don't think you will be able to get this to work.

I know that someone once found out that iTunes uses some kind of daemon program to communicate with your iDevices. I'm not sure if this is still true, but that daemon is undocumented but 'available'. I have no more clues than this, maybe you get lucky and find something on Google.

I'd go with wireless communication, I don't think speed is such an issue if we're talking about small instruction sets.

Also [there's this](http://redpark.com/c2db9.html), but I'm not sure if that will be of any help to you.

UPDATE:
found this post: [Where is the mount point for the iPod/iPhone in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844586/where-is-the-mount-point-for-the-ipod-iphone-in-mac)
Which should help you write to the iDevice disk. You should be able to continuously look for filesystem updates on your device to process the data, and vice versa, to establish some kind of transfer system.

Comment: Thanks. That update looks particularly useful. I will try it and report back with the results.