# How can I Import iPhone photos and videos in mac application?

Tags: macos, import

I want to import photos and videos from iPhone whenever iPhone is connected to mac device like drop box ..... . 
As soon as iPhone connected to mac I am not getting any notification . I have tried NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification but it doesn't worked for me ........   Please help...
Thanks in advance

Comment: To import camera roll photos to your Mac, you need a program that will recognize the iPhone as a camera. But don't know how to recognize iPhone as camera

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844586/where-is-the-mount-point-for-the-ipod-iphone-in-mac                                                  But this is not working for me.

Comment: This api was developed to allow access to iOS devices. Can we access photos and videos by using this library. I have compiled this library but do not how to use it in project                  http://www.libimobiledevice.org/