# Using libgpod on Windows

Tags: c#, iphone, windows, synchronization, ipod

I'm coming from this question: [Where is the mount point for the iPod/iPhone in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844586/where-is-the-mount-point-for-the-ipod-iphone-in-mac)

Although it's OSX and not Windows, I assume that the fact, that there is no mount point is still true. However libgpod requires a mount point for getting data from the device. How can I connect to the iDevice with libgpod (and how can I select from multiple connected devices, if it's possible)? Do I need to use libimobiledevice (I couldn't really find a function for mounting media of device, or to get mount point)?