# Find mount point of an USB device in OSX

Tags: macos, usb, mount

In order to share a device between a host and a Docker container, I would like to know the path to the mounting point for a given device, a smartcard reader in this case.

Using **ioreg -p IOUSB -t**, I can see the device (CCID USB Reader) :

```
iMac:~ $ ioreg -p IOUSB -t
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 13>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@fd000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x100000257, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (42 ms), retain 7>
  | +-o IOUSBHostDevice@fd100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000258, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (45 ms), retain 14>
  |   +-o Card Reader@fd110000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002a8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (89 ms), retain 11>
  |   +-o IR Receiver@fd120000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000002c9, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (139 ms), retain 14>
  |   +-o CCID USB Reader@fd130000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000a1d, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (28 ms), retain 17>
```

However this does not help me to find on which /dev/??? this device is mapped to.
The **mount** command does not give details on non-storage devices.

EDIT 1:

Here is the result of a **ls -l** command on the **/dev/** directory :

```
iMac$ ls -l /dev > before.txt
iMac$ ls -l /dev > after.txt
iMac$ diff before.txt after.txt 
25,27c25,27
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root     wheel      14,  18 10 avr 10:40 io8log
< cr--r--r--  1 root     wheel      14,  10 10 avr 10:39 io8logmt
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root     wheel      14,  19 10 avr 10:42 io8logtemp
---
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root     wheel      14,  17 10 avr 10:40 io8log
> cr--r--r--  1 root     wheel      14,  18 10 avr 10:39 io8logmt
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root     wheel      14,  10 10 avr 10:42 io8logtemp
```

There is no new entry. And I am not sure if io8log* file relate to the USB reader.
The **mount** command output also does not change when plugging on unplugging the USB reader.

EDIT 2:

According to [Where is the mount point for the iPod/iPhone in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5845648/957103), OSX does not use mount non-data device with mouting points but connects directly instead.
In that case, is there still a way to share this device with a Docker container ?

Comment: might not be what you want, but a simple trick would be to unplug the usb device run command ls /dev/USB* ... plug back in usb and run again... just incase you are stuck and need urgent hack job...or the command mount?

Comment: Unfortunately, I see no difference when plugging the USB reader for commands `mount` and `ls -l /dev`.