# How to share an non-storage USB device between host and container on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, usb, smartcard

I recently created a Docker image available on the Docker HUB : [oroger/pypassport](https://hub.docker.com/r/oroger/pypassport/).

This image rely on the presence of an USB smartcard reader shared between the host and the container. This work fine on Ubuntu using either `--device`or `--priviledged` and a volume on `/dev/bus/usb`.

However did not find a way to share such a device on OSX.
I did [some digging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36523760/957103) and it appears that non-storage USB devices are not mounted under `/dev`.

I was wondering if there was another way to use the same image on OSX. If not I would also be interested in any way to would require to create a new image some other way.

Comment: Not *completely* programming related, I'll leave it be because it is close enough. But I think you might get better help on an OSX Q/A site.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get an answer to this? You need to set up USB forwarding in virtualbox for the docker-machine (aka boot2docker) VM. This article helped me out: http://reprage.com/post/configure-android-development-environment-with-docker

Comment: Can you please add the relevant content to your answer? The link might be gone tomorrow.